# Forward HTTP traffic to virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have the following setup:
One Windows Server 2012 with an external, static IP address (Name: P).
On that physical server a virtual server is running via Hyper-V (Name: V).

V hosts a secure website (HTTPS).
P has the Remote Desktop Gateway service installed, which also works via HTTPS.

My problem now is that I can't change the port of the RD Gateway, because Windows 7 clients need to be able to connect, too.

I thought about solving it like this:
If the host name of the HTTPS traffic is the IP address, it should be handled by P.
If the host name of the HTTPS traffic is the DNS name of the server, it should be forwarded to V.

I can't use the Routing feature of "Routing and Remote Access", because it works on the TCP level and not the HTTP level and I only have one external IP address.

So, how would I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run an HTTPS-aware proxy on P and proxy incoming requests with the right Host header to the internal IP address of the VM.

I don't know if IIS is capable of this but if it isn't, you could run a dedicated proxy on port 443 and put IIS on a different port on the physical box.

---

You could also ask your hosting provider for a second IP address.  They aren't *that* hard to come by.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A second IP address would be an option, but as this is only a temporary setup, I am not willing to pay for it. I haven't found a way to do this with IIS, but that might be just me not knowing the proper terminology. What proxy would you recommend?

Comment: [This question might have some answers for you](http://serverfault.com/questions/95427/windows-replacement-for-haproxy).  I have used both Apache and nginx (on Linux) for this purpose and was happy with both of them.

Comment: Thanks. ARR as per mamus answer is what I am using now. Googling brought up [this nice tutorial](http://forum.wegotserved.com/index.php?/tutorials/article/98-configure-iis-for-reverse-proxy/)

Answer (score 1):

ARR is your answer here.  Look for articles by Scott Forsyth on handling ARR.  He has a IT pro series with some covering ARR.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/Web+Pro+Series/ARR/default.aspx